# Updating the content of a div using jquery waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I am using [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

In the HTML given below, when the waypoint of a `hardware` class is reached it should update the content of the `<div>` having class `number` with the content of the `div.current` within the `div.hardware`.

My html:

```
<div class="number"></div>

<div class="hardware">
    <div class="current">1</div>
</div>

<div class="hardware">
    <div class="current">2</div>
</div>

<div class="hardware">
    <div class="current">3</div>
</div>

<div class="hardware">
    <div class="current">4</div>
</div>
```

I have this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.hardware').waypoint(function() {
        var addNumber = $(this).find('.current').content();
        $('.number').content(addNumber);
    });
});
```

but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: *"but this doesn't work for me"* - what exactly is not working..?

Comment: It will not update the content of the <div class="number"></div>

Comment: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(this).find('.current').content()') this is my console error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery method is [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), not `content()`

```
$(function() {
 $('.hardware').waypoint(function() {
    var addNumber = $(this).find('.current').contents();
    $('.number').contents(addNumber);
 });
});
```

P.S: [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method even retrieves comment nodes. For getting the text content from an element, it's better to use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Comment: No, now it says: SyntaxError: Expected token '}'

Comment: @Sake that means the code above worked. now you have some other problem with your code... you probably not closing a function somewhere...